# How to load a specific Slider Revolution for mobile-only?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, responsive, revolution-slider

I know that there is a **responsive** feature for [revolution-slider](/questions/tagged/revolution-slider), but unfortunately it still loads all the mobile assets on desktop and vice versa, adding time to the page-load.

So I'd prefer to have 2 distinct sliders, one per device.

What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you are setting your [revslider](/questions/tagged/revslider) in your pages.

I think that the best way to achieve what you really want (need) is using php with conditional rules:

1) In your templates with conditional based on mobile detection. This way you will avoid loading 2 [revslider](/questions/tagged/revslider) at the same time.

You could use `wp_is_mobile()` conditional wordpress function for this purpose:

```
<?php
    if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
        echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider alias="my_desktop_slider"]');
    } 
    else
    {
        // mobile devices
        echo do_shortcode('[rev_slider alias="my_mobile_slider"]');
    }
?>
```

2) In a custom shortcode with that conditional:

```
if( !function_exists('rev_slider_detection') ) {

    function rev_slider_detection( $atts ) {

        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'alias' => '' // the alias name of your desktop rev-slider
        ), $atts));

        $output = '[rev_slider alias="';

        if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
            // For desktop only
            $output .= $alias . '"]';
        } else {
            // For mobile only
            $output .= $alias . '_mob"]';
        }

        return $output;
        // or (because untested)
        // return do_shortcode('" . $output . "');
    }

    add_shortcode('my_rev', 'rev_slider_detection');
}
```

You will use it this way: `[my_rev alias="my_revslider_alias_slug"]` and you will need to have 2 instance of a rev slider, the first one for desktop with some alias name ( `home` for example) and the second one for mobile with same alias name **+ "_mob"** ( `home_mob` for example).

Reference:

- [WP codex wp_is_mobile](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile)
- [WP codex do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/)
- [Shortcode Generator](https://generatewp.com/shortcodes/)

You can also elaborate a more accurate script to detect tablets and phones, then use it as a conditional for different devices types.

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that while the general approach in this answer is correct, `wp_is_mobile()` is a near useless function. It should not be part of WordPress in it's current form.

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me. You need just one [short code] for normal/desktop version, _mob version will be automatically chosen.

```
if( !function_exists('rev_slider_detection') ) {

    function rev_slider_detection( $atts ) {

        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'alias' => ''
        ), $atts));

        $output = '[rev_slider alias="';

        if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {
            // For desktop only
            $output .= $alias . '"]';
        } else {
            // For mobile only
            $output .= $alias . '_mob"]';
        }

        return do_shortcode($output);
        // or (try this if not working)
        // return $output;
    }

    add_shortcode('my_rev', 'rev_slider_detection');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

echo do_shortcode($output); // works for me