# Different slider layouts for desktop and mobile in Slider Revolution

Tags: css, revolution-slider

i have the great Slider Revolution included in my Template, which i would like to use. For my layout i need two different layouts, so that it looks nice on desktop as well as on mobile devices.

I know i can use different sliders. I found a thread on stackoverflow handling this very well, here: [How to load a specific Slider Revolution for mobile-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666445/how-to-load-a-specific-slider-revolution-for-mobile-only)

My question, is there any way i can use on mobile screen an auto layout for the slider with overflow and on desktop one with cover and overflow: hidden? Then i do not need to implement two different slides to achieve the same - less work.

I tried to find out the position where the layout code is implemented, but i could not find the correct line. Yeah i know maybe its easy, but i am not that pro in coding.

Anyway, hopefully you guys can help me out.

Thx Ruven

Comment: Does no one has an idea, maybe a js code to track the viewport like @media and then inline cs or sth.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no one could help me out with my question or do not have time to do it. I am a bit disappointed about this.

Anyway, i ended up with my own solution. I use auto mode as standard and then i add custom css in form of a media querie, where i define at which min width the slider switches in fullscreen mode:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
 ##sliderID_wrapper, #sliderID { z-index: 9999 !important; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; position: fixed !important; top: 0 !important; left: 0 !important;  }
}
```

Hopefully i could help out when someone has the same problem.

Greetz